# Getting the value of a script's "var" using Selenium with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-chrome, var

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url_goes_here")

p_id = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")
```

This procures me the script I need. I don't need to execute it, as it's already executed and running upon initial page load. 
It contains a variable named "task". How do I access its value with Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex module `re` can help you with that:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url_goes_here")

p_id = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")

for script in p_id:
    innerHTML=script.get_property('innerHTML')
    task=re.search('var task = (.*);',innerHTML)
    if task is not None:
        print(task.group(1))
```

What this does is look through the innerHTML of each script and, from the defined search pattern (`'var task = (.*);'`), capture the matching string group (`(.*)`). Print out the group if a match is found.

Comment: First off, you're the only person in this thread so far who seems to have gotten what I'm actually asking, namely to extract the inner contents of the appropriate <script> tag which I've already scraped, and go from there. So thanks!
Now, as for this: ```script.get_property('innerHTML')```  
It returns an empty string! :(

Comment: Strange..if you do a `.get_attribute` instead of `.get_property` do you still get an empty string?

Comment: I never got around to trying ```.get_attribute```, but I eventually solved my problem by extracting the appropriate element via the ```.find_elements_by_xpath``` rather than via by tag name as depicted in the original question and *THEN* using your ```.get_property('innerHTML')``` suggestion. My issue is solved now, and since you were the only one who at least put me on the right path to its solution, I will mark your answer as correct! Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can access value of `tag` or any `element` of html via `.text` or `.getText()`

Comment: I was aware of these methods, but the first one returns an empty string to me, no matter what I try it on. Whereas the second gives: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `find_elements_by_tag_name`() which returns list of elements.
Iterate that list and check element.text contains `task` then `print text` of that element.

```
p_id = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")
for id in p_id:
    if 'task' in id.text:
        print(id.text)
```

Comment: ```Since you are using find_elements_by_tag_name() which returns list of elements..```


Any better suggestion for scraping for scripts specifically? Would searching by... let's say, XPath, produce a better formatted output or something?

Second, this is the actual content of an element of the output list that gets produced by the execution of the find_elements_by_tag_name():

```<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="53d2976784532dd4717abff68170b22a", element="8d9f432d-7a2e-47e0-8023-d6c092ee9620")>```

As you can see, it's not very legible.

Comment: @Alexander : I am extremely sorry if haven't understood your requirement.I believe you are searching script tag which contains the text `task` is that right?

Comment: the script tag is already FOUND and stored in a list. Question is, how do I extract the value of its variable "task" from that raw data stored in the list.

Comment: Well for that you need to post that script details.Regular expression will definitely work to extract the value.

Answer (score 0):

#Use `Xpath` instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("url_goes_here")

p_id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"ADDXPATH")

p_id.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```